# How should I name a function which shows or hides an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function to display or hide some elements. What I want to do is to manage the display of those elements regarding a value.

How should I replace the term `toggle`? Toggling for me means 'show the element if it's hidden, or hide it if it shown.' (yes, I mean toggling visibility)

```
function togglePassengers() {
    var nbPassengers = $("#nbPassengersForTravel").val(),
        $passengers = $('#d_passenger').find('fieldset');

    $passengers.each( togglePassenger );

    function togglePassenger(i){
        $passenger = $(this);
        if( ++i <= nbPassengers )
            showPassenger($passenger);
        else
            hidePassenger($passenger);
    }

    function showPassenger($passenger){
        $passenger
            .removeClass("hidden")
            .find("select.age option[value='-1']").remove();
    }

    function hidePassenger($passenger){
        $passenger.addClass("hidden");
        var $passengerAge = $passenger.find("select.age");
        if ( ! $passengerAge.find("option[value='-1']:first-child").length )
            $passengerAge.prepend("<option value='-1'>---------</option>").val('-1');
    }
}
```

Comment: I think, I may go for `changeVisibilityOfPassenger(i)`

Comment: SetPassengerVisibility?

Comment: I think a function named `setSomething` should take the value setted as a parameter. Which is not the case, here.
(And I prefer the camelCase style :-) ). Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Naming**

I think `togglePassenger` is not the only naming problem in your code.

A function parameter should not be a single letter except in a very limited number of cases. But I don't think that this is not one of them; a reader does not automatically understand what `i` actually does.

I would also rename `nbPassengers`, because it is unclear what `nb` means.

What I think your function does is show the first n passengers, and hide the rest. If that is the case, I would not use `toggle`, because as you said, there really is no toggling going on. You could go with something like `updateVisibility` to avoid this confusion, although it's a bit unconcrete. Whatever name you do choose, I would add a comment to the function explaining what it does.

**Misc**

- I would use curly brackets even for one line statements to avoid future bugs
- your spacing is sometimes inconsistent (eg spacing around variable in function calls)

Comment: `updateVisibility` sounds good !

However, I never use single letter variable BUT for index.
I think it is readable.
I could go for `passengerIndex`, true.

for `nbPassenger`, I don't know... `numberOfPassengers` seems a bit long. But at least I should put `nbPassengers` with plural.

Thanx.

Comment: I don't think that `numberOfPassengers` is all that long. But you could also use `passangerCount`, which is quite clear and shorter.

Comment: With `updateVisibility` I may use `passengerIndex` instead of `i` because the subject is not in the function name.